# how can i load independent file jsp or servlet?

Tags: jspx

how can i load independent file jsp or servlet?

Comment: question is unclear. Try to improve

Answer (score 1):

In your jsp surround the menu code with an if block,

```
<c:if test="userProvider.LoggedIn">
   //menu code
   <jsp:include page="userspecific.jsp" flush="true" />
</c:if>
```